# get string from another class in android

Tags: android

Im having problem to pass a string to another class. Anyone can solve this problem?
Thanks and very appreciate for helping.

**1st class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Intent  myIntent;
    Intent intent;
    String n;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                System.out.println("Pg1");
                n="title";;
                System.out.println("n1"+n); 
                System.out.println("p1getn "+getn()); 
                myIntent=new Intent (v.getContext(),spg.class);
                 startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
            }
        });

    }

    public String getn(){
        System.out.println("nn"+n);
        return n;
    }
}
```

**2nd class**

```
public class spg extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sec);
        MainActivity am = new MainActivity();
        System.out.println("Pg2");
        System.out.println("n2"+am.n);
        System.out.println("getn2"+am.getn());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to pass the string to another activity in the intent you're using to start the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity .this, spg.class);
intent.putExtra("string_name", your string);
startActivity(intent)
```

Now on the OnCreate method of your spg activity you can fetch the extras like this

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("string_name");
```

Comment: But by using this way, could i pass a string from the 1st class to 3rd class?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730041/how-to-check-if-my-button-is-clicked-in-another-activity/19730730#19730730), it is the solution to your problem.
instead of buttons, you need to change it to your situation (Strings)
More clarifications: Activty1 is `MainActivity`. Activity2 is `spg`
if anything else is unclear, please comment.